# Add a "CC recipient" to Outlook 2010 VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Can someone please show me how to add a "Cc recipient" to this code? The "To Recipient" and code all work as intended. Thank you for your time.

```
Sub ForwardEmail(item As Outlook.MailItem)
' Dim oExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
Dim oMail As MailItem
' Set oExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer

On Error GoTo Release

' If oExplorer.Selection.item(1).Class = olMail Then

Set oMail = item.Forward
oMail.Subject = oMail.Subject
oMail.HTMLBody = "Have a nice day." & vbCrLf & oMail.HTMLBody
oMail.Recipients.Add "email address here"

' oMail.Save
oMail.Send

' End If

Release:
Set oMail = Nothing
' Set oExplorer = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `oMail.CC`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
set oRecip = oMail.Recipients.Add("email address here")
oRecip.Type = olCC
```

or

```
oMail.CC = "email address here"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful. I appreicate your time.

Comment: Please mark the post as answer if it answers your question. Thank you.

Comment: I would vote up but I just started and don't have quite enough rep points yet.

Comment: In case you need to refer to the values directly, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/enumerations-outlook and specifically for recipients the [OlMailRecipientType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/olmailrecipienttype-enumeration-outlook).