# VBA - Sending an Outlook Email to unknown number of recipients

Tags: vba, excel

Almost a month ago, I have already posted a question that is somewhat similar with this current question of mine.

[Sending Outlook Email with multiple recipients from Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092863/sending-outlook-email-with-multiple-recipients-from-excel-file)

But today, I want to develop codes that do not care whether the TO field only contains 1 recipient and perhaps EMPTY for CC. I was able to come up with this two types of codes:

A.

```
   'Set Recipients
    Range("A2").Select
        Set Recipient = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))

    'Set Recipients
    Range("B2").Select
        Set CC = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown))


    On Error Resume Next

        With OutlookMailItem

            .Display

            'Assign Recipients in TO field
            For Each sTo In Recipient
                Set myRecipient = OutlookMailItem.Recipients.Add(sTo)
                myRecipient.Type = olTo
                myRecipient.Resolve
                If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then
                    myRecipient.Delete
                End If
            Next sTo

            'Assign CCs in CC field
            For Each sCc In CC
                Set myCc = OutlookMailItem.Recipients.Add(sCc)
                myCc.Type = olCC
                myCc.Resolve
                If Not myCc.Resolved Then
                    myCc.Delete
                End If
            Next sCc
        End With
```

However, these codes only works with two and more email addresses. When I tried to supply only 1 value for TO and none for CC, it displays Run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)' : There must be at least one name or contact group in the To, Cc, or Bcc box.

B.

```
For Each sTo in Recipients
    receiver = receiver & sTo.Value & ";"
Next

For Each sCc in CC
    CCs = CCs & sCc.Value & ";"
Next
```

But these codes lead to an unresponsive Excel file.

Is there an error with my codes? Or any suggestions on how I can make my TO and CC fields dynamic. Dynamic in a sense that I could assign ONE or MORE for TO and NONE or MORE for CC.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe (untested)

```
Dim rngTo As Range, rngCC As Range

With ActiveSheet
    'using xlUp is typically safer than xlDown...
    Set rngTo = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set rngCC = .Range(.Range("B2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
End With

AddRecipients OutlookMailItem, rngTo, olTo
AddRecipients OutlookMailItem, rngCC, olCC
```

Since there's a lot of common code you can create a sub to handle adding the recipients:

```
Sub AddRecipients(olMail, rng As Range, recipType)
    Dim c As Range, myRecipient
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            Set myRecipient = olMail.Recipients.Add(c.Value)
            myRecipient.Type = recipType
            myRecipient.Resolve
            If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then myRecipient.Delete
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: "not working" is not a useful description of what happens when you run code.  What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Problem in your code is that in case of zero or one recipient (or CC) your `Recipient` variable contains almost entire column. For code A, the problem is that there are many empty cells and looping through them results in `There must be at least one name or contact group in the To, Cc, or Bcc box` error. For code B, I guess looping through 1 048 576 rows (twice!) is just a little too much for excel.