# How can I create email message with address name?

Tags: vba, outlook

I followed the below example.

https://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-a-new-message-using-vba/

I want to display address book name when automatically making the email draft.

For example, in this case,

I am able to display "BZ@gmail.com" in the address field but I want to display an address book's name "Business Team" because "Business Team" is easier to see.

Here is my code. it is almost same as the example code.

```
Public Sub CreateNewMessage()
Dim objMsg As MailItem

Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objMsg
  .To = "Alias@domain.com"
  .CC= "Alias2@domain.com"
  .BCC = "Alias3@domain.com"
  .Subject = "This is the subject"
  .Categories = "Test"
  .VotingOptions = "Yes;No;Maybe;"
  .BodyFormat = olFormatPlain ' send plain text message
  .Importance = olImportanceHigh
  .Sensitivity = olConfidential
  .Attachments.Add ("path-to-file.docx")

 ' Calculate a date using DateAdd or enter an explicit date
  .ExpiryTime = DateAdd("m", 6, Now) '6 months from now
  .DeferredDeliveryTime = #8/1/2012 6:00:00 PM#

  .Display
End With

Set objMsg = Nothing
End Sub
```

I can send only by "alisas@domain.com" and when I see the opened draft, email address displayed.

How can I display address book name on draft?

Comment: If **Business Team** is in the GAL under Exchange environment, Outlook tries to resolve names after a certain time. There is no *MsgBox* in codes by your link, so what is your code? Add your code by Edit your post.

Comment: don't mind msgbox... I just mean... I dont want answers that uses msgbox. in my code there are no msgbox.

Comment: I'll upload my code, wait a minute

Comment: You may have to use [`MailItem.Recipients.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/recipients-add-method-outlook) to use the Display Name instead of SMTP address.

Comment: Wow you are great!

Comment: Thank you... but how can I add CC by address name..?

Answer (score -1):

For the first part of your question, refer to [Recipients.Add Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/recipients-add-method-outlook).

For CC's, you need to change the recipient type, see answer for this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904656/add-a-cc-recipient-to-outlook-2010-vba).