# How to add a CC to current macro for Reply with attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to modify my macro for **Reply All With Attachments** to add also in CC my bosses e-mail because I have to do it often.

I was trying to incorporate it from [here](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=53) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904656/add-a-cc-recipient-to-outlook-2010-vba) but I am no Pro and receive the 424 error :(

```
    Set objRecip = objMail.Recipients.Add("theboss@thecompany.com")
    oRecip.Type = olCC
```

could you please help modify the current macro to add an email address to CC?

my current macro

```
Sub ReplyWithAttachments()
Dim oReply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oItem As Object
Set oItem = GetCurrentItem()
If Not oItem Is Nothing Then
Set oReply = oItem.Reply
CopyAttachments oItem, oReply
oReply.Display
oItem.UnRead = False
End If
Set oReply = Nothing
Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub

Sub ReplyAllWithAttachments()
Dim oReply As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oItem As Object
Set oItem = GetCurrentItem()
If Not oItem Is Nothing Then
Set oReply = oItem.ReplyAll
CopyAttachments oItem, oReply
oReply.Display
oItem.UnRead = False
End If
Set oReply = Nothing
Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem()
...
End Function

Sub CopyAttachments
...
End Sub
```

Comment: Appears there is a typo in each line. oReply not objMail `Set objRecip = oReply.Recipients.Add("theboss@thecompany.com")` and objRecip not oRecip `objRecip.Type = olCC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is pull the CC list from the original email and then append it with your boss email:

```
If Not oItem Is Nothing Then
    Set oReply = oItem.Reply
    oReply.CC = oItem.CC & ";theboss@thecompany.com"
    CopyAttachments
    oReply.Display
    oItem.UnRead = False
End If
```